# Inheritance, Sub-Class, Printing with super.print() in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, printing, polymorphism, super

I have 4 different classes. One titled `Student`, one `Instructor`, one `Person` and `Main`. Below is my code:

**Student:**

```
public class Student extends Person {
public void print() {
    super.print();
    System.out.println(", credits: " + credits);
}
}
```

**Instructor:**

```
public class Instructor extends Person{
private double salary;
public double getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(double newSalary) {
    salary = newSalary;
}

public void print() {
    super.print();
    System.out.println(", salary: " + salary);
}
}
```

**Person:**

```
public class Person {

private String name;
private String id;

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String replacementName) {
name = replacementName;
}

public String getID() {
return id;
}

public void setID(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public void print() {
    System.out.print(name + ", student ID: " + id);
    }

}
```

**Main:**

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Instructor instructor = new Instructor();
    instructor.setName("Hani Javadi");
    instructor.setID("888777666");
    instructor.setSalary(11111);
    instructor.print();

    System.out.println("--- --- ---");

    Student student1 = new Student();
    student1.setName("Joe Loop");
    student1.setID("810123456");
    student1.addCredits(10);
    student1.print();

    Student student2 = new Student();
    student2.setName("Mary Collection");
    student2.setID("811987321");
    student2.addCredits(25);
    student2.print();

    Student student3 = new Student();
    student3.setName("Ke Method");
    student3.setID("810010101");
    student3.print();
}

}
```

**When I go to output this code, the result is this:**

---

```
Hani Javadi, student ID: 888777666, salary: 11111.0 

Joe Loop, student ID: 810123456, credits: 10

Mary Collection, student ID: 811987321, credits: 25 

Ke Method, student ID: 810010101, credits: 0
```

**However, the output needs to have the first line as:**

---

```
Hani Javadi, instructor ID: 888777666, salary: 11111.0
```

---

Can anybody help solve this trivial mistake? I have been laboring for hours trying to find a way to fix it by adding an `if` statement in the superclass `Person` but nothing seems to work. Is there a simple way to make the instructor print statement to show instructor ID rather than student ID?

Comment: If an Instructor instance should not print a student Id, then either an Instructor is not a Person, or a Person should not print a student Id.

Comment: How about making `print` completely abstract in `Person`? Currently it has `Student`-specific behaviour, which is wrong for the base class.

Comment: It is usually a bad practice to extend concrete classes. Your question is a perfect example. As others suggested if `Person` is concrete class then it needs to say ", person ID: ". Otherwise it needs to be an abstract class with either abstract method that returns occupation that will be used it your `print` method or lets subclasses fully override the `print` method.

Comment: @tsolakp Why do you think extending concrete classes is (usually) a bad idea?

Comment: You can search on this topic. But here are some of them. 1) what's the point? If you need to define a type then just use interface. If you want to define shared behavior then use abstract class (I call it templating) 2) Someone can modify concrete class without realizing that it serves as base class and can introduce side effect to all subclasses. 3) There is no way to force subclasses to provide specific behavior and subclasses won't know what methods to implement since all methods are concrete.  With abstract class you can define abstract methods that subclasses need to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo,
It happens because you got 'student ID' in Person class, it works on abstract level

For example, you can try to use next approach in Person class:

```
public void print() {
    System.out.print(name + ", " + getClass().getName() + "  ID: " + id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I struggle with abstract classes, and this helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should move the printing of the `id` field entirely into the subclasses, rather than in the parent class, so they can determine the appropriate leading indicator.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is, your `Person` class says `studentId=...`. This is quite a nice training on on polymorphism, and it already shows you where your approach went wrong.

The thing is, `Person` shouldn't have anything that is `Student`-specific. If it's an ID of a `Person`, it should say `personId=...` instead. If the ID is something entirely different between `Student` and `Instructor`, you need to do those prints in those two classes instead.

Polymorphism, inheritance. These tools can do awesome things. But they can backfire if used improperly, which is what has just happened to you.

---

Now, seriously, don't do it like that:

```
if (this instanceof Student) {
    System.out.print("student ID=" + id)
} else if (this instanceof Instructor) {
    System.out.println("instructor ID=" + id);
} else {
    // some default here, or I don't know.
}
```

This absolutely works, but it's a disaster from design perspective. What @Skytrace mentioned works, and isn't even nearly as ugly. However, it would only work in this special case where class name is equal to what you want to display. And if someone refactors it, renaming `Student` class to e.g. `StudentDto`, you will see `StudentDto ID=...`, which is no longer nice.

Answer (score -1):

Create another method in the Class Person below

```
   public void print() {
    System.out.print(name + ", student ID: " + id);
    }
```

e.g.

```
public void print2() {
    System.out.print(name + ", Instructor ID: " + id);
    }
```

then call it in your main class as
instructor.print2();

Comment: This is a bad idea as the OP now has to know the type of `Person`. The solution should involve over-riding `print()`.

Comment: First, you need to learn Java to a pretty advanced level. Then you can help by answering others' questions. If you want/need to get points on StackOverflow before that, try editing questions and/or answer of others, fixing typos and formatting. This answer helps nobody.